# Amcharts not showing balloonText of highest value

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am using 3D Stacked Column Chart from Amcharts plugin. The output is correct but not able to view the highest value on bar graph.[image: Amchart Of Bench]

When I try to hover on the highest value the label is not shown.
Below if the amcharts script.

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
            "theme": "light",
            "labelText": "[[title]]: [[value]]",
            "type": "serial",
            "titles": [{
                "text": "Benches Classification by Borough",
                "size": 16
            }],
            "valueAxes": [{
                "stackType": "3d",
                "unit": "",
                "position": "left",
                "title": "Bench Counts:",
            }],
            "startDuration": 1,
            "graphs": [
            {
                "balloonText": "backless : [[value]]",
                "fillAlphas": 0.9,
                "lineAlpha": 0.2,
                "title": "backless",
                "type": "column",
                "valueField": "backless"
            },
            {
                "balloonText": "backed:[[value]]",
                "fillAlphas": 0.9,
                "lineAlpha": 0.2,
                "title": "backed",
                "type": "column",
                "valueField": "backed"
            }],

            "plotAreaFillAlphas": 0.1,
            "depth3D": 73,
            "angle": 60,
            "categoryField": "Borough",
            "categoryAxis": {
                "gridPosition": "start"
            },
            "export": {
                "enabled": true
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior is to not show a balloon if there's no room for it (3d charts are a bit more needy). You can work around this by setting a [`minMaxMultiplier`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#minMaxMultiplier) in your value axis to small factor to increase the maximum of the value axis; you'll want to force the [`minimum`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#minimum) to 0 if your data is always positive to avoid a negative axis.

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "theme": "light",
  "labelText": "[[title]]: [[value]]",
  "type": "serial",
  "dataProvider": [{
      "backed": 113,
      "backless": 56,
      "Borough": "Manhattan"
    },
    {
      "backed": 190,
      "backless": 64,
      "Borough": "Bronx"
    },
    {
      "backed": 127,
      "backless": 38,
      "Borough": "Brooklyn"
    },
    {
      "backed": 135,
      "backless": 50,
      "Borough": "Queens"
    },
    {
      "backed": 105,
      "backless": 31,
      "Borough": "Staten Island"
    }
    //Lower Manhattan is not a separate borough ;)
  ],
  "titles": [{
    "text": "Benches Classification by Borough",
    "size": 16
  }],
  "valueAxes": [{
    "stackType": "3d",
    "unit": "",
    "position": "left",
    "title": "Bench Counts:",
    "minMaxMultiplier": 1.05,
    "minimum": 0
  }],
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [{
      "balloonText": "backless : [[value]]",
      "fillAlphas": 0.9,
      "lineAlpha": 0.2,
      "title": "backless",
      "type": "column",
      "valueField": "backless"
    },
    {
      "balloonText": "backed:[[value]]",
      "fillAlphas": 0.9,
      "lineAlpha": 0.2,
      "title": "backed",
      "type": "column",
      "valueField": "backed"
    }
  ],

  "plotAreaFillAlphas": 0.1,
  "depth3D": 73,
  "angle": 60,
  "categoryField": "Borough",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start"
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 300px"></div>
```

Another alternative is to create your own balloons using an external div and leverage the [`rollOverGraphItem`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#rollOverGraphItem) and [`rollOutGraphItem`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#rollOverGraphItem) events to trigger the balloon. There's an example of this in AmCharts' [knowledge base](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/displaying-rollover-balloon-outside-chart-area/).

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Previously I was trying to changed the position of the ballontext as it was not visible.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely the label is outside the view. You can right-click to inspect the chart to see if the label is there.

Try adding some margin at the top?

```
chart.marginTop = 20;
```

Comment: <g class="amcharts-graph-column amcharts-graph-graphAuto1_1505750281007" transform="translate(224,416)" visibility="visible" aria-label="backed Brooklyn 388">
This is the inspect element. It shows 388. But as the value is closer to 400 it is not been shown.